# How to get what App's link going to be in PlayStore before uploading?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to add share link in my app including the downloading link of android play. But since my app is not launched on PlayStore, I don't have download link currently. How can I include download link now?

Comment: you can use beta testing in google play console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you.

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // this is your playstore url id parameter
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

According to [google support](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3086746), the url for your app is/will be

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**package_name**

For example, if your package name is com.mypackagename.myapplication, when you publish this app your url will be:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mypackagename.myapplication

---

Here is a practical example: [google chrome app url](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome), see the url in your browser